# javascript unobtrusive

Tags: javascript, html, unobtrusive-javascript

i have an html page, which is consist of many hyperlink like this inside body tag...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/?id=313354">User Name</a>
```

then i decide to use unobtrusive javascript ... then i'd like to change all the "a" tag to be...

```
<a id="354313" href=#>User Name</a>
```

when i click the second link above, i want that it'll call a function like the first link does,...
my question is how to get all the "a" element inside body tag then apply a function depend it's id...

Comment: Don't decide to use obtrusive JavaScript. That is moving backwards.

Comment: yeah that's right... sorry, i'm wrong...

Comment: Is using javascript libraries like jQuery acceptable? That should make this job relatively easy...

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: ok.. i'm new here... many apologies for ma mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function WindowLoad() {
    var arrLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrLinks.length; i++) {
        var oLink = arrLinks[i];
        var sCurHref = oLink.href;
        if (sCurHref.indexOf("?id=") >= 0) {
            var ID = sCurHref.split("?id=")[1];
            if (ID.length > 0) {
                oLink.id = ID;
                oLink.href = "#";
                oLink.onclick = function() {
                    document.location.href = sCurHref;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This will iterate all the links, changing the visible HREF to "#" and preserving their functionality, applying the proper ID. (Though you didn't say what's the use of that ID)

Feel free to mess around with the live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/uMbEY/

Comment: @Afrig so like I said before, feel free to Accept the answer.. it's simple matter of clicking the empty "V" sign to the left, making it green.

Comment: @Afrig now you know, please do it on your other questions as well, it's never too late. :)

Answer (score 2):

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com), something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var id = this.getAttribute('id');
    // Do something...
});
```

If you want it to work on all elements ever created, use this:

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
    var id = this.getAttribute('id');
    // Do something...
});
```

Comment: @Afrig: In that case, take a look at Zaje's answer. Is there a particular reason you're not using a JavaScript library like jQuery, or just because you don't want to?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are trying.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var alA = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var aCounter=0;aCounter<alA.length;aCounter++) {

var singleA = alA[aCounter];
singleA.onclick = function () {

window.open = "http://www.example.com/?id="+singleA.id;
}

}

<script>
```

Comment: yeah... it helps me... but sometimes, inside the body tag there are 2 or more "a" element with the same id... will it working?...

Comment: @Afrig: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID. If that's the case, use classes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<script language="javascript">
   function myFunction(id)
   {
      alert(id);
   }
</script>

<a id="354313" onclick="myFunction(this.id);" href="#">;User Name<;/a>
```

Not sure though  Test it :)

Comment: i mean, how to apply add event listener to all the "a" tag... while im using javascript obtrusive...

Comment: This is highly obtrusive. He meant unobtrusive (at least I hope so)

Answer (score 0):

I will rather say that add class to the links u want to handle this way

```
<a class="mylink" ... >User Name </a>
```

Now read the elements by class name. If you are using new browsers or any JS library like JQuery its great.

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("mylink") //Method in Mozilla Browser
```

Above are the links that you can process nicely without getting into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Function that you want to call
function fake(id)
{
  // Your content
}

// Get all "a" elements and put it in an Array
var links = window.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; ++i)
{
    fake(links[i].id);
}
```